# Unportable code produces "no operator matches these operands" error in template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

With some C++ code that does explicit template instantiation:

```
struct Data { } ;

template<int T1>
struct Collection {
   template <int T2, int T3>
   static void copyRelevantData( const Data& param, Data& res ) { }
};

template<int T1>
struct Manipulation {
   template<int T2, int T3, int T4>
   static void doStuff( ) {
      Data from, to ;

      Collection<T1>::copyRelevantData< T2, T3 >( from, to ) ;
   }
};

template
void Manipulation<2>::doStuff<0, 0, 0>() ;
```

I'm seeing the following sort of error (intel 13 icpc output) :

```
vv.C(26): error: no operator ">" matches these operands
            operand types are: int > Data
        Collection<T1>::copyRelevantData< T2, T3 >( from, to ) ;
                                                 ^
```

or (g++ 4.1.2) :

```
vv.C: In static member function 'static void Manipulation<T1>::doStuff()':
vv.C:15: error: no match for 'operator>' in 'T3 > (from, to)'
vv.C: In static member function 'static void Manipulation<T1>::doStuff() [with int T2 = 0, int T3 = 0, int T4 = 0, int T1 = 2]':
vv.C:20:   instantiated from here
vv.C:15: error: invalid operands of types '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and 'int' to binary 'operator<'
```

This code compiles with the IBM xlC compiler (v12).  I'm not sure why the template parameter list is being interpretted as a greater than, but there is clearly a portability issue here.

I'm interesting in knowing how to adjust the code to work with all compilers.

Also, should this code work (i.e. and possibly a bug with both the intel and GCC compilers), or is it invalid language use (and possibly also indicates that the xlC compiler has a bug since that compiler allows this code?)

Comment: That's not explicit instantiation, it's explicit specialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `template` keyword, and perhaps also use a more recent version of g++. This compiles on the latest g++ and clang++:

```
Collection<T1>::template copyRelevantData< T2, T3 >( from, to ) ;
```

Comment: He seems to be using xlC (IBM's compiler), not gcc

Comment: One of the compilers he tried was gcc, so hopefully this fix will also work for xlC and icpc (neither of which I have access to).